# Keep selection persistent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, select

I'm need to keep selected values persistent when the page reloads.  I'm using a multiselect plugin with jQuery for a dropdown selection menu.  Is this possible?  I don't know a whole lot about this, so if I sound dumb, sorry. :)

```
<select multiple="multiple" style="width: 135px;" name="platform[]" id="platform">
<option value="platform_1">Platform 1</option>
<option value="platform_2">Platform 2</option>
</select>

<select id="2" multiple="multiple" style="width: 165px;" name="features[]" id="features">
<optgroup label="Group One">
<option value="feature_1">Feature 1</option>
<option value="feature_2">Feature 2</option>
<option value="feature_3">Feature 3</option>
<option value="feature_4">Feature 4</option>
<option value="feature_5">Feature 5</option>
<optgroup label="Group Two">
<option value="feature_6">Feature 6</option>
<option value="feature_7">Feature 7</option>
<option value="feature_8">Feature 8</option>
</select>
```

Comment: cookies or local storage, or preferably local storage with cookies as a fallback.

Comment: Use cookies or LocalStorage if your using HTML5

Comment: To keep selections persistent on page reload you'll have to store the data in a cookie or find some other storage method.

Answer (score 3):

here is a example of what you might need:

```
$("#platform").val(getCookie("platform"));
$("#2").val(getCookie("feature"));

$("#platform option").click(function(){
    document.cookie = "platform="+$(this).val();
});
$("#2 option").click(function(){
    document.cookie = "feature="+$(this).val();
});

function getCookie(c_name) {
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {
 x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
 y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jorgehdez/CBNFe/3/)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand what this is doing.

Comment: When you click on a <option> element it sets a cookie for that <select> with the value of the clicked element, at the start of the page checks if there is a cookie and put the select the option with that value. If you click an option in the jsfiddle and click Run (reload the page), the element selected is the same.